# How to read the data set by set in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a huge millions of data(csv file) to read using Spring Batch job.

Is there any way to read the data set by set like

- "Read first 200000 data and process them and write them and stop the step/batch job
- Restart the step/job and Read next 200000 data and process them and write
  them and stop the step/batch job
- Restart the step/job and Read next 200000 data and process them and write
  them and stop the step/batch job"

========================================================================

```
      @Bean
        public Job readCSVFilesJob() {
            return jobBuilderFactory
                    .get("readCSVFilesJob")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<CSVData, CSVData>chunk(10000)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .writer(writer())
                    .build();
        }

      @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Bean
        public FlatFileItemReader<CSVData> reader()
        {
    reader.setResource(new InputStreamResource(inputStream));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);  
       /* reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());*/

        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {
            {
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                    {
                        setDelimiter(",");
                        setStrict(false);

                         setNames(new String[]{"col1","col2"});
                    }
                });
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CSVData>() {
                    {

                        setTargetType(CSVData.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return reader;
}
```

Thats the code I have for spring batch reader which reads the data based on chunk size I have given(10000).

Comment: What about configuring the chunk size as `200000`?
`stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<CSVData, CSVData>chunk(200000)`

Comment: your config will read data chunk by chunk (what you call set by set), 10000 items at a time.